# how to call twice nested method in angular 1.x?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My HTML looks like this:

**Controller HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <first-directive></first-directive>
</div>
```

**first-directive HTML**

```
<li>
 <second-directive></second-directive>
</li>
```

**Controller JS**:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', (#scope) => {
 $scope.foo = function() {
  console.log('do smthn');
 }
});
```

**first directive:**

```
app.directive('first-directive', function(){
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: '/partials/first-directive.html',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
   // some data
  }
  controllerAs: function(){}
 }
}
```

**second directive:**

```
app.directive('second-directive', function(){
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: '/partials/second-directive.html',
  controllerAs: function(){}
 }
}
```

So i have controller with nested directive and there is another nested directive. When i'm trying to call $parent.foo() from first-directive it works. When i'm trying to call $parent.$parent.foo() from second-directive it doesn't work. I tried also use `ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl"` and `ctrl.foo()` from second-directive syntax, but it doesn't work either. Why?

Answer (score 0):

have you added second directive inside

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
```

are you using in ng-if before second directive? because ng-if also creates its own scope

Comment: I haven't add second directive inside ng-controller. The only place where i added second-directive is inside first-directive. I am not using ng-if anywhere.

Comment: can you try $parent.foo() from second directive as it is not having isolated scope.

Comment: i don't think it is two level nesting

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$rootScope.$broadcast`in nested directive controller and then on parent controller use `$rootScope.$on`.

In second directive

```
  app.directive('second-directive', function(){
     return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: '/partials/second-directive.html',
      controller: function($rootScope){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('parentCtrl',{});
              }
      }
  }
```

In parent controller

```
 app.controller('Ctrl', ($scope,$rootScope) => {
 $scope.foo = function() {
      console.log('do smthn');
  }
  $rootScope.$on('parentCtrl', function (event, data){
    //do the parent task here  
  }
});
```

You can also use service function  to communicate between the child controller and parent controller.

Answer (score 0):

As second nested directive doesn't have isolated scope, try $parent.foo()